# Replace dynamically value of options while passing the output of a php function

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace, var

I have a string `($options)` stored in a PHP var which contains of a series of `<option>` elements which look like the following:

```
<option class="level-0" value="898">Text 1</option>
<option class="level-1" value="33">&nbsp;Text 2</option>
<option class="level-2" value="543">&nbsp;&nbsp;Text 3</option>
<option class="level-1" value="547">&nbsp;Text 4</option>
<option class="level-0" value="3328">Text 5</option>
```

I want to replace the content of each `value` with the result of a function which takes the former value to generate a URL. The URL string (which is variable) should become the new value for each corresponding `<option>`. I want to retain the rest exactly as it is.

I'm not sure if this is achievable with `preg_replace`, yet I would know how to do it if each option was an array with keys, but it's a variable string... How would you do it?

Comment: Is there no possibility to do it when you are building the option list / generating the string?

Comment: unfortunately not :) it's a wordpress problem: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81597/how-to-determine-the-depth-of-a-term-in-a-custom-taxonomy/ the function wp_dropdown_categories() returns a dropdown (which can be echoed or put in a variable), but I need to change those values with pretty permalinks - I can do this with get_term_link() which takes the value (it's the term ID) and returns a pretty permalink. I would have been able to do it before the dropdown was generated if wp_dropdown_categories allowed a custom walker to do so, but it seems it doesn't.

Comment: then html parser or regex it is...

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $options);

$new_options = array();

foreach ($lines as $option_line) {
   //do the preg replace for each line (quick and dirty regexp)
   $replaced_string_value = preg_replace('/>(\w+)<\//i', '>replacement<\\', $option_line);

   //add it to the new array   
   $new_options[] = $replaced_string_value; 
}

$options = implode(PHP_EOL, $new_options);
```